# Python - How to merge and swap every nth element of two lists

Tags: python, list, slice

I have two lists:

```py
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
```

My desired output is:

```py
l3 = [1, 2, 3, 'd', 'e', 'f', 7, 8, 9, 'j', 'k', 'l']
```

How to achieve this? I have looked at slicing but I couldn't figure out how to take a group of elements to swap them.

Answer (score 6):

```py
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']

n = 3

l3 = [elem[(idx // n) % 2] for idx, elem in enumerate(zip(l1, l2))]
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a version:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
l2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"]
a = (l1, l2)
l3 = [a[(i // 3 % 2)][i] for i in range(len(l1))]
```

i take `l1` and  `l2` as sublists of `a` and select one of them for every 3 elements.

this version would then be more pythonic (has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57553801/4954037) first):

```
l3 = [l1_l2[(i // 3 % 2)] for i, l1_l2 in enumerate(zip(l1, l2))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
n = 3

[j[0] if (i // n % 2 == 0) else j[1] for i, j in enumerate(zip(l1, l2))]

#[1, 2, 3, 'd', 'e', 'f', 7, 8, 9, 'j', 'k', 'l']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should o the trick:

```
l3 = [l2[i] if (i%6>2) else l1[i] for i in range(0, min(len(l1), len(l2)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit more of an explicit solution (and can be refined further), but will do the trick given `l1` and `l2` are the same size:

```py
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']

def combine(l1, l2, split_size):
    iterations = int((len(l1)/split_size))
    l3 = []
    for x in range(0, iterations):
        if (x % 2) == 0:
            for i in range(0, split_size):
                l3.append(l1[(x * split_size) + i]) 
        else:
            for i in range(0, split_size):
                l3.append(l2[(x * split_size) + i]) 
    return l3

print(combine(l1, l2, 3))
```

## Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 'd', 'e', 'f', 7, 8, 9, 'j', 'k', 'l']
```

Answer (score 0):

below function will merge using an interval value "n":

```
def mergeWithInterval(n, l1,l2):
    l = []
    c = 0
    f = True
    for i,j in zip(l1, l2):
        if f == True:
            l.append(i)
        else:
            l.append(j)
        c+=1

        if c%n == 0:
            f = not f
    return l


l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
mergedList = mergeWithInterval(3,l1,l2)
print(mergedList)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'd', 'e', 'f', 7, 8, 9, 'j', 'k', 'l']
```